# change meaning of "paragraph" for TeX input?

Tags: cursor-motions, wrapping, filetype-tex

I'm writing LaTeX code which has a lot of sections like this

```
\begin{definition}
blah blah blah ...
...
\end{definition}
```

In normal text, I'm very fond of `gq]` to rewrap everything nicely. Inside a block section like the above, that wraps the end command too, which I'd rather keep on a separate line.

Is there a way to tell vim that a line starting `\end` ends a paragraph? Or is there another formatting command I can use (I have `<F8>` mapped to `gq]`, I don't mind redefnining it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it employs the `ie` (*inside-environment*) custom text object, available in a number of places: e.g. in the plugin [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), or with [vim-textobj-latex](https://github.com/rbonvall/vim-textobj-latex) (and there are others). With this functionality, then the rewrap command becomes:

```
gqie
```

or

```
gwie
```

(to maintain cursor position).

If you only want to reformat text *from current text position* (I see that this is your use case) to the paragraph end, you can probably make do with the following construct (no plugins required):

```
gq/\(^\s*$\|\\end\)
```

This will format to either an empty line, or a line containing the `\end` keyword, whichever comes first. So you could use this mapping:

```
:nnoremap <F8> gq/\(\\end\\|^\s*$\)<CR>
```

Comment: `gqie` does what I want when inside a begin...end block, in the main text body it tries to wrap everything until \end{document} - is there a way to tell it to stop at the next blank line?

Comment: Well, outside an environment - maybe the default `gqap` ?

Comment: See the updated answer, for a possible `F8` remapping.

Comment: I presume I have a typo somewhere as the following doesn't work: `:map <F8> gq/\(^$\|^[%]$\|^\\end\)<CR>`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to match a completely empty line (`^$`), a line with only a % comment character (`^[%]$`) or a line starting `\end` (`^\\end`).

Comment: I think you must use `\\|` as separator instead of `\|` when mapping.

Comment: That was it! (Although it's `\\|` not `\\I`.)
The expression that I finally chose: 
`gq/\(^$\\|^[%]$\\|^\\end\)`

Comment: Yes, ninja edited :)